# What sql permissions required to join two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I want to give access to a user to be able to query two tables and join them:

```
SELECT * from table1 JOIN table2 on table1.t_id=table2.id
```

What necessary permissions do I have to grant?

I tried doing:

```
GRANT SELECT ON table1 TO 'df'@'%';
GRANT SELECT ON table2 TO 'df'@'%';
```

But it seems like I need to include more?

Comment: Can you select from one of these tables alone?

Comment: If the same user 'df' have select permission on both of the table, then the should be executed.

Comment: @jarlh no -- it seems like this is a credentials error -- sorry about that, I'll close the question.

Comment: Divide and conquer! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm

Comment: Select privileges on both tables are enough